# Does spring MVC server create connection for request data?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, web, connection

I'm developing an web application using spring MVC framework. Now I'm wondering if the connections are being closed for each client request. I mean, if I have 1000 users logged in my site, am I going to have 1000 connections opened? If so, is there a way to make client and server communicate without creating an conection or closing them once the request is received?
I'm sorry for this question, but I'm starting to use this framework and I haven't set anything related to it when I installed the framework.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with Spring, read up on servlets and its containers like Tomcat or Netty.

Comment: Do you know if Tomcat creates connections for each request? I haven't found anything related to it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web requests hit the webserver, fetch the HTML and resources such as CSS files and pictures and close the connection again. You won't have permanent connections. This means if 1000 users will load a site all at the same time you'll have 1000 concurrent requests. If they load the site at different times within 5 minutes you won't have concurrent requests, or at least less at a time. Web requests are usually handled within a few to 300 milliseconds. It's not the same like opening a permanent database connection or anything like that. The login will also be handled over a web request and a session will be created up on successful login. The session can be handled in different ways. You can read more about sessions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29. You should also read about Spring Security.

So to answer your question, no when 1000 users are logged in you won't have 1000 open connections. But each time a user loads a page you will have a connection.

You can minimize the connections to your server by using for example a Javascript based Frontend that takes care about most of the tasks client side and only communicates with the server over REST for example.

I hope this helps and answers your question.

Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: Thank you Chris! This has completely clarified my question!